# Python scatter plot different colors depending on value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe which i want to make a scatter plot of.

the dataframe looks like:

```
       year  length  Animation
0      1971     121       1
1      1939      71       1
2      1941       7       0
3      1996      70       1
4      1975      71       0
```

I want the points in my scatter plot to be a different color depending the value in the Animation row.
So animation = 1 = yellow
animation = 0 = black
or something similiar

I tried doing the following:

```
dfScat = df[['year','length', 'Animation']]
dfScat = dfScat.loc[dfScat.length < 200]    
axScat = dfScat.plot(kind='scatter', x=0, y=1, alpha=1/15, c=2)
```

This results in a slider which makes it hard to tell the difference. [image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `c` parameter in `scatter`

```
df.plot.scatter('year', 'length', c='Animation', colormap='jet')
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing. I am just using their index instead of the name. Good heads up tho.
But how would i go around changing the color completely depending on their value. I dont have anything inbetween 0 and 1.
For example that 1 = yellow and 0 = black on the slider.

Comment: Try using there column name.  Use a different colormap.

Comment: Cheers, Didn't know about colormaps. :)

Answer (score 18):

You can also assign discrete colors to the points by passing an array to c=
Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {"year"      : (1971, 1939, 1941, 1996, 1975),
     "length"    : ( 121,   71,    7,   70,   71),
     "Animation" : (   1,    1,    0,    1,    0)}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

colors = np.where(df["Animation"]==1,'y','k')
df.plot.scatter(x="year",y="length",c=colors)
plt.show()
```

This gives:

```
   Animation  length  year
0          1     121  1971
1          1      71  1939
2          0       7  1941
3          1      70  1996
4          0      71  1975
```

[image]